# T4 Template not working with List as a parameter

Tags: c#, t4

I have a T4 template.

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic"#>
<#@parameter name="Stats" type="System.Collections.Generic.List<SiteStat>" #>
<#@parameter name="Cnt" type="System.Int32" #>

    This is a test.  Why is this not working <#= Cnt #>
    <table>
        <# foreach (SiteStat stat in Stats)
           { #>
             <tr><td>Test name <#= stat.node #> </td>
                 <td>Test value <#= stat.region #> </td> </tr>
        <# } #>
     </table>
```

The simple integer is passing into the system fine
but the more complex List is not.

It does not generate any content inside the table tags.

Edit 4/26/2021:
My SiteStat is defined as follows

```
namespace ScheduledJobsService
{
    [Serializable]
    public struct SiteStat
    {
        public string region { get; set; }
        public string district { get; set; }
        public string system { get; set; }
        public string node { get; set; }
        public float a1score { get; set; }
        public float a1delta { get; set; }
        public float a7score { get; set; }
        public float a7delta { get; set; }
        public SiteStat(string region, string district, string system, string node, float a1score, float a1delta, float a7score, float a7delta)
        {
            this.region = region;
            this.district = district;
            this.system = system;
            this.node = node;
            this.a1score = a1score;
            this.a1delta = a1delta;
            this.a7score = a7score;
            this.a7delta = a7delta;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using ScheduledJobsService.SiteStat inside my teplate as so

```
<#@parameter name="Stats" type="System.Collections.Generic.List<ScheduledJobsService.SiteStat>" #>
```

But it wont compile claiming that SiteStat does not exist in the ScheduledJobsService namespace

Comment: `List<SiteStat>`? the SiteStat type is not an included type in this template. Also I'd pass data in with XML or JSON and serialize inside the template as passing Type of Type parameters is both annoying and tricky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to pass the **full type** name to `SiteStat`.

Also, keep in mind that, as from documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/t4-parameter-directive?view=vs-2019):

> You can declare parameters of any remotable type. That is, the type
> must be declared with `SerializableAttribute`, or it must derive from
> `MarshalByRefObject`. This allows parameter values to be passed into the
> AppDomain in which the template is processed.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the .tt file add your parameters as public class members inside a "Class feature control block".
This block must go to the end of the file.

```
<#+
public SiteStat Stats{ get; set; }
#>
```

you can use your template as follows:

```
YourTemplate t = new YourTemplate
{
    Stats = yourStatsObj
};
```

For more information regarding the T4 syntax, see MSDN article Writing a T4 Text Template. [Writing a T4 Text Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/modeling/writing-a-t4-text-template?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN)